# Does "serializable" also mean that it's lockable

Tags: sql, serialization, transactions

Here's an final exam question for a Database Fundamentals class. I've read the book, stuff online.. I can't figure out if "*serializable*" also means that the schedule is `lockable` or not. What I mean is.. I understand that for the schedule to be isolated, you have to have non-conflicting *reads* & *writes*, but then it also says "if the transactions are not isolated(i.e., serializable).."

By determining if the schedule is isolated, does this include determining if locks(lock-W(x), lock-R(x)) and unlocks can be placed inside the schedule, is `"serializable"` both *isolated* and *lockable*?

Here's the question:

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks I posted it there too.